# How do I get around initializing variables inside init() if they are initialized by loading .json data?

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I have a struct PrimaryUser() whose variables get loaded in through a .json file parser. One of those variables are a date string in the ISO8601 format. I want to have that value automatically converted to a Date type variable.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to make this code run automatically upon creation of PrimaryUser():

```
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
        self.dateOfBirth = dateFormatter.date(from: dateOfBirthISO8601)!
```

If I put this code inside init(), I get the error:

```
'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
```

If I try making dateOfBirth a lazy variable, I run into this error:

```
Lazy properties must have an initializer
```

Again to reiterate, all the PrimaryUser() variables will be initialized with data from a .json file through a parser that's totally separate from PrimaryUser(). So it doesn't make sense to initialize the variables inside PrimaryUser().

Here's what PrimaryUser() looks like:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct PrimaryUser: User, Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var dateOfBirthISO8601: String
    lazy var dateOfBirth: Date
    init() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
        self.dateOfBirth = dateFormatter.date(from: dateOfBirthISO8601)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initiate lazy like this

```
struct PrimaryUser:  Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var dateOfBirthISO8601: String
    lazy var dateOfBirth: Date? = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
        let date  = dateFormatter.date(from: dateOfBirthISO8601)
        return date
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom date decoding strategy when using `JSONDecoder` to turn your string into a `Date`.

Just pass your `DateFormatter` into the `JSONDecoder` with:

`decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)`

That way you can get rid of the lazy variable or a custom initialiser.